# DBText fields are shifted down when sending Report Builder report to Printer

Tags: delphi, reportbuilder, richtext

I have a report template created in Report Designer. It is basically a RichText template with some DBText fields dropped on it. When I generate the report all the DBText fields are populated with data from database.

When I preview the generated report on screen it looks correct. But when I print the same report all DBText fields are shifted about one line down as on below screenshot:

[image]

If I remove RichText component and use only Labels and DBTexts then there is no problem with printing.

Has anybody faced the same issue in the past? How to solve it?

Note: I am using Delphi 5 with Report Builder 6.02 Enterprise.

Answer (score 0):

As I found out the printing issue was caused by the RichText component used together with DBTexts components in the designer. It looks like Report Builder issue but I found two solutions for that:

1. You can remove RichText component from the template and use only Latels, DBTexts, etc. Printing will be fine in this case.
2. If you want to keep using RichText then you need to embed database fields inside the RichText Editor using angle brackets. You can see the example below:

[image]

Note, that it will only work when the “MailMerge” option is ticked (right click on the RichText component):

[image]

There is one limitation though. You can use only one dataset per report. However this can be solved by using subreports as for every subreport you can assign a different dataset (via Report -> Data menu).